# How to combine multiple regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to combine multiple regex values. For example: /Harry/ and /Potter/ to [ /Harry/, /Potter/ ]. I want to pass this is in a mongoDB function.

I have tried this:

reg = new RegExp(reg + ',' + new RegExp(words[i]));

But it messes it up

I am inputting an array words = ["Harry", "Potter", "Killer"];
I want it to look like this in regex: [ /Harry/, /Potter/, /Killer/ ]

```
var reg = '[ ' +new RegExp(words[0]);
    for (i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
            reg = new RegExp(reg + ',' + new RegExp(words[i]));
    }
    reg = reg + ' ]';
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and the expected result. Are you trying to do [Alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: You want to find Harry or Potter or Killer? Or you want Harry and Potter and Killer?

Comment: No, that's not an example. Are you trying to match `Harry` or `Potter` or `Killer`? Or are you trying to do something else? Did you check the link I provided?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do alternation

Comment: Then all you need to do is join the strings using a pipe character, that is, `/Harry|Potter|Killer/` which is perfectly explained in that link. You can either do that manually or using `new RegExp("/" + YourArray.join("|") + "/";`.

Comment: Yes, sir I am a beginner can you provide me with some code. Sorry to irritate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're looking for [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). All you need to do is map your `words` into `RegExp` objects like so:

```
const words = ["Harry", "Potter", "Killer"];
const regex = words.map(e=>new RegExp(e)); // [/Harry/, /Potter/, /Killer/]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, please mark as solution if it's working well :)

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal Please note that this doesn't do alternation; it just creates an array of `RegExp` objects. It might very well be what you want. I'm just pointing that out because this isn't what you described in the comments above.